# XMLHTTP.Open method not recognized

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I try to create an object of type `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` but when i call the method Open I get an error :

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Here is my code:

```
set objXmlHttp =  server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

objXmlHttp.Open "POST", strURL , false
```

I have tried using the TLS 1.2 but the same thing happens.
The `strURL` variable receives an address with HTTPS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could do with more information, what about `strURL` is it possible to post it maybe obfuscating the host-name or something? At the moment there isn't enough information to suggest anything. See how to create a [mcve]. Also here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37462944/692942) I posted to another question only hour ago, might help you.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the error is occurring on the `objXmlHttp.Open` line? I would suggest it is happening after when either trying to call `objXmlHttp.Send()` or retrieving the response and not getting what you expect, seen that scenario many times.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the TLS 1.2"?

Comment: At first it seemed that we could not use the new object based on the current settings, that were made through TLS 1.0. But actually it seems that this not the case and it works fine with any of the protocols.