# read all elements from another page using classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a way to read a another page's elements and grab the whole HTML code?

let's say for example i want to get all the HTML from this page : http://localhost/test3.html

Thank you!

Comment: [See comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700013/web-scraping-in-classic-asp#comment72550103_42700013)

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I use:

```
function http_post (strUrl, data)
    ' call another URL (e.g. ASP or PHP script) via HTTP and POST. "data" should be GET-style parameter string or empty '
    dim xmlHttp
    Set xmlHttp = Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    With xmlHttp
        .Open "POST", strUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(data)
        .Send data
        if .Status < 400 then
            http_post = .responseText
        else
            ' do error logging here if you want '
            http_post = false
        end if
        .abort()
    End With
    set xmlHttp = Nothing
end function
```