# How to consume a asp.net web api in classic asp?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp-classic

I have a sample web API want to consume it in asp file, please guide me with the steps to consume web API in classic asp.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: You'll need to [use XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462944/692942) to make a request and handle the response.

Comment: @Lankymart - I've never used WinHttpRequest before, does it have any advantages over Msxml2.XMLHTTP?

Comment: Thank you friends for your response. I'm able to consume the web api in classic asp.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is the asp code.

```
  <%
  Dim Id
  Id = Request.QueryString("Id")

  url = "http://localhost:50464/api/values/"+Id

  Dim oXMLHttp
  Set oXMLHttp=Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  oXMLHttp.open "GET", url,false
  oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  oXMLHttp.send 
  response.write oXMLHttp.responseText
  Set oXMLHttp = Nothing
  %>
```

API url: http://localhost:50464/api/values