# cURL with Classic ASP

Tags: curl, vbscript, winhttprequest

I'm trying to get SyncCentric to work with a legacy Classic ASP site that is currently using Amzpecty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

The cURL request should be:

```
curl "https://app.synccentric.com/api/v3/products" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer your-api-token" \
  -d "identifiers[0][identifier]=B00YECW5VM" \
  -d "identifiers[0][type]=asin" \
  -d "identifiers[1][identifier]=B00USV83JQ" \
  -d "identifiers[1][type]=asin" \
  -XPOST
```

The ASP code I was going to use is below, but I have no idea how to convert the cURL request into the data string:

```
Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim url: url = "https://app.synccentric.com/api/v3/products"
Dim data: data = ""

With http
  Call .Open("POST", url, False)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "My API key")
  Call .Send(data)
End With

If Left(http.Status, 1) = 2 Then
  'Request succeeded with a HTTP 2xx response, do something...
Else
  'Output error
  Call Response.Write("Server returned: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I post data using cURL in asp classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462580/how-can-i-post-data-using-curl-in-asp-classic)

Comment: No, although I did look at it. What I can't work out is how to format the data string from the cURL parameters. I tried every combination I could think of but nothing worked :(

Comment: The example in the duplicate question shows how to format it `key=value&key=value` and so on…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in the [CURL man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d), under the `-d, --data <data>` section:

> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

So you need to specify the key=value separated by an ampersand as you would with a raw HTTP POST.

```vb
Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim url: url = "https://app.synccentric.com/api/v3/products"
Dim data: data = "identifiers[0][identifier]=B00YECW5VM&identifiers[0][type]=asin&identifiers[1][identifier]=B00USV83JQ&identifiers[1][type]=asin"

With http
  Call .Open("POST", url, False)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer your-api-token")
  Call .Send(data)
End With

If Left(http.Status, 1) = 2 Then
  'Request succeeded with a HTTP 2xx response, do something...
Else
  'Output error
  Call Response.Write("Server returned: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
End If
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [How can I post data using cURL in asp classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462944/692942)

Comment: Thank you so much - that worked. I couldn't work it out before that. Thanks!